# Can I tap into an exterior light fixture to connect different things

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, exterior, light

I just ran mc cable to a exterior light fixture(dusk to dawn one) from an exterior gfci outlet (which is outside near ground level), I'd like to put and outlet, switch and/or lights in attic close to cable by exterior light, can I wanted to have junction box so I could run the cable up there, could I get power from the light fixture(in attic exterior) to run to a junction box, then use that box for my switch, lights, etc?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard to understand what you're asking, with one long sentence and not a lot of details. If you  edit your question  to be clearer and add more info (e.g. a diagram?) then we'll be more likely to  be able to help you.

Comment: So you want to go from outdoor gfci -> dusk dawn light -> attic switch -> attic light? Mc cable is an odd choice outside and not to code if it doesn't have a corrosion resistant sheath. Usually plastic conduit with THWN. See: https://forums.mikeholt.com/showthread.php?t=125769. In any case, I don't see a problem with what you want to do, as long as you aren't overloading the circuit and with LED lights nowadays that is rarely an issue as they don't consume much power. I'd take issue with the fact that if you were in the attic and the gfci outlet tripped, you'd be in the dark.

Comment: Ok so basically I have an exterior gfci outlet that is coming from my panel, i took power from the outlet and ran in up my walls to my attic to put an exterior light up(its dusk to dawn light). I want to know if i could take power from the light and run more stuff up there in the attic such as a light, a switch, and outlet, etc. And if i can do that should i just do a junction box and run everything from there?